# what are the Jquery scripts files for Ajax.BeginForm in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Ajax.BeginForm

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("checklogin", "home", null, new AjaxOptions { 
    UpdateTargetId = "resultId",   
    HttpMethod="Post" }, new { id = "_forgetForm" }
))
```

but result is showing on next page

I have included

```
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but no effetcs
what are the .js files and what there order to use 
Ajax.BeginForm

Answer (score 6):

You need only 2 scripts in that order:

```
1) jquery-1.7.1.min.js
2) jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
```

The `Microsoft*.js` scripts are completely deprecated starting from ASP.NET MVC 3. You should no longer use them.

The `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` are necessary if you want to enable unobtrusive client side validation. They are not required for Ajax.* helpers to work, only for client side validation.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post, but I thought I should post this for MVC 5 apps. You can easily install AJAX scripts into your MVC application by opening the Nugets Manager as in screen shot below and installing the AJAX scripts.

[image: How to add AJAX Scripts to your MVC 5 App]

Answer (score -1):

I got solution :
If any body want to use Ajax.BeginForm, He has to include scripts plugins in following orders

1) jquery-1.7.1.min.js
2) MicrosoftAjax.js
3) MicrosoftMvcAjax.js
4) jquery.validate.min.js
5) jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
6) jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Comment: This is not the correct solution. You don't need the Microsoft* scripts nor the .validate scripts for this to work. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15114299/29407